# Simple MySQL queries take far too long

Tags: mysql, performance, debian, innodb

I'm using InnoDB in MySQL (0.5GB database) on Debian 6.0.

This morning (after 120 days of perfect uptime), suddenly the server hung (in fact the server hung a second time in the last two days) and I had to reboot it through hoster CP.

In kern.log, I've got this:

```
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.208104] INFO: task mysqld:9755 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.233913] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.234249] mysqld        D ffff88007dc67170     0  9755   1241 0x00000000
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.234472]  ffff88007dc67170 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 ffffffffa021c4c2
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.234815]  ffff880009ff1ad8 ffff880009ff1ad8 000000000000f9e0 ffff880009ff1fd8
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.235181]  0000000000015780 0000000000015780 ffff88007d177170 ffff88007d177468
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.235549] Call Trace:
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.235732]  [<ffffffffa021c4c2>] ? ext4_mark_iloc_dirty+0x46e/0x4f7 [ext4]
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.235963]  [<ffffffffa021cd61>] ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x18f/0x1c4 [ext4]
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.236212]  [<ffffffff812fc2ab>] ? __mutex_lock_common+0x122/0x192
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.236422]  [<ffffffff812fc3d3>] ? mutex_lock+0x1a/0x31
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.236626]  [<ffffffff81113c8c>] ? __blockdev_direct_IO+0x1d3/0xa60
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.236852]  [<ffffffff810b51c2>] ? generic_file_buffered_write+0x1f5/0x278
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.237097]  [<ffffffffa021da26>] ? ext4_ind_direct_IO+0x10e/0x1be [ext4]
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.237320]  [<ffffffffa02205c9>] ? ext4_get_block+0x0/0xe2 [ext4]
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.237528]  [<ffffffff810b57bf>] ? generic_file_aio_read+0xf6/0x536
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.237794]  [<ffffffff81071dbf>] ? wake_futex+0x31/0x4e
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.237984]  [<ffffffff810ef061>] ? do_sync_read+0xce/0x113
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.238278]  [<ffffffff8100f79c>] ? __switch_to+0x285/0x297
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.238471]  [<ffffffff81065046>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x2e
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.238687]  [<ffffffff81048282>] ? finish_task_switch+0x3a/0xaf
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.238897]  [<ffffffff810efa84>] ? vfs_read+0xa6/0xff
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.239090]  [<ffffffff810efb34>] ? sys_pread64+0x57/0x77
Apr 16 09:43:35 lhost kernel: [76680.239290]  [<ffffffff81010b42>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

And just before complete blackout:

```
Apr 16 09:45:32 lhost kernel: [76800.253284]  [<ffffffff81010b42>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Apr 16 09:56:29 lhost kernel: [77453.643191] Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = -788398275 ns)
Apr 16 10:01:01 lhost kernel: imklog 4.6.4, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

So I decided to turn the slow queries log on, and this is what was logged:

```
# Time: 130416 13:38:41
# User@Host: lhost[lhost] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 2.059521  Lock_time: 0.000026 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use lhost;
SET timestamp=1366105121;
UPDATE t_fuser SET DATE_UPDATE=now()  WHERE ID = 992277;
# Time: 130416 13:56:42
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.663760  Lock_time: 0.000037 Rows_sent: 230  Rows_examined: 230
SET timestamp=1366106202;
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `lhost`;
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.693291  Lock_time: 0.000031 Rows_sent: 230  Rows_examined: 230
SET timestamp=1366106202;
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `lhost`;
# Time: 130416 14:00:19
# User@Host: lhost[lhost] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 7.139369  Lock_time: 0.000210 Rows_sent: 122  Rows_examined: 3027170
```

This looks really weird to me. I've tried to execute similar queries (there's more complicated ones on this log, but that's not the point) directly through the console and got results much faster, so it's not indexes.

What can I do to address this? Is it hardware?

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2012       1355        657          0         40        627
-/+ buffers/cache:        687       1325
Swap:         2047        129       1918
```

Thank in advance for your advice.

Additional data:

[image: CPU Usage - munin]
[image: Memory Usage - munin]

PROFILE of slow query:

```
mysql> show profile;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000020 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000111 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000003 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000001 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000002 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000001 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000003 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000032 |
| System lock                    | 0.000004 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000006 |
| init                           | 0.000074 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000020 |
| statistics                     | 0.000171 |
| preparing                      | 0.000027 |
| Creating tmp table             | 0.000160 |
| executing                      | 0.000003 |
| Copying to tmp table           | 4.572503 |
| Creating sort index            | 0.009622 |
| Copying to group table         | 0.029744 |
| Removing duplicates            | 0.010745 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000086 |
| Sending data                   | 0.004350 |
| end                            | 0.000008 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.001207 |
| end                            | 0.000005 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000040 |
| end                            | 0.000004 |
| query end                      | 0.000003 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000018 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000005 |
| freeing items                  | 0.002768 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000004 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000029 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000006 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
34 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to execute fsck and then check IO performance: dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/mysql/file1 bs=512 count=10000

Comment: 5120000 bytes (5.1 MB) copied, 0.0198583 s, 258 MB/s
 Command being timed: "dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/mysql/file1 bs=512 count=10000" 
 User time (seconds): 0.00
 System time (seconds): 0.01

for the first time and 437MB/s for following tries

Comment: what you can do is to run you query with profiling: SET profiling = 1; your query ; SHOW PROFILE;

Comment: It's possible that u r right. I've updated post.

`| Copying to tmp table           | 4.572503 |`

Comment: Looks like you have not enough memory

Comment: Munin doesnt agree :) 

Also, it's very unlikely the reason of blackouts. Am I right?

Comment: Here are conditions when MySQL using temptable: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html